# How to setup a Codeigniter Project to work with DynamoDB?

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-dynamodb

I have been trying to figure out how to setup a php project in Codeigniter framework to work with DynamoDB. The information provided by AWS in its document is not enough to configure its DynamoDB SDK with CI libraries.

If anyone has done this, please share your knowledge.

Comment: What have you tried? After Googling "codeigniter and dynamodb" the first result, was this; http://glynrob.com/database/dynamodb-in-codeigniter/

Comment: Yes Craig I tried glynrob solution, but it's not working as that is implemented with older AWS Sdk.

Comment: Have you tried this one?

https://github.com/ashiina/codeigniter-dynamodb-model/

Comment: @NirajBurde, did you find a solution ?